# Compile issue with MSVC std::isfinite

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi the following codes won't compile in MSCV; it gives error

(9): error C3615: constexpr function 'Test' cannot result in a constant expression due to the use of std::isfinite!?

```
constexpr int Test(double value)
{
    if (!std::isfinite((double)value))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

//}

gcc is fine, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`std::isfinite` isn't marked as `constexpr` until C++23.  Apparently gcc's standard library has already implemented this feature and MSVC's hasn't yet.

Make sure, when you compile with MSVC, to ask for the latest version of the standard with `/std:c++latest`.  But I'm guessing they just haven't made that change yet.

In the meantime, you could write your own implementation of `isfinite` that is `constexpr`.  I think the Wikipedia page on IEEE floating point has enough detail to come up with the appropriate test condition.  I think the infinities and NaN values have all bits of the exponent field set to 1.